# PHP mail() function not sending on new server

Tags: php, mysql, email, vcf-vcard

Having some issues with a PHP script that sends emails (code below). Basically, it populates a vCard file with contact information stored in an sql db and attaches it to an email using the php mail() function.

I had this working perfectly on a shared hosting server a few days ago... but I recently migrated everything over to a VPS and it magically stopped working. Mail() continues to return true on send, but the actual email never arrives in my inbox.

```
//sendemail: emails a vCard when passed an email address and name
function sendemail($address, $scanreduser)
{   
    include('../dbconnect.php');
    $info = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE usernum='". $usernum ."' LIMIT 1 "));
    $vcard_content  = "BEGIN:VCARD\r";
    $vcard_content .= "VERSION:3.0\r";
    $vcard_content .= "N:".$info[lname].";". $info[fname] .";;;\r";
    $vcard_content .= "FN:".$info[fname]." ". $info[lname] ."\r";
    $vcard_content .= "ORG:".$info[company].";\r";
    $vcard_content .= "TITLE:".$info[title]."\r"; 
    $vcard_content .= "EMAIL;type=INTERNET;type=WORK;type=pref:".$info[email]."\r";
    $vcard_content .= "TEL;type=WORK;type=pref:".$info[phone]."\r";
    $vcard_content .= "item2.URL;type=pref:".$info[website]."\r";
    $vcard_content .= "item2.X-ABLabel:_$!<HomePage>!\$\_\r";
    $vcard_content .= "X-ABShowAs:COMPANY\r";
    $vcard_content .= "END:VCARD";

    $email_subject = "Your vCard from " . $info[fname] . " " . $info[lname];
    $fileatt_type = "application/octet-stream"; // File Type
    $fileatt_name = $info[fname] ."_". $info[lname] .".vcf";

    $headers = "From: Ben@scanred.com";
    $today = date("l, F j, Y, g:i a");

    $message = "<br />Simply open the attached vCard file to view/download the information<br />";
    $message .= $today." PST<br /><br />";
    $message .= $info[name]."<br />";

    $data = $vcard_content;
    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

    $semi_rand = md5(time());
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
    "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
    " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

    $message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
    "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
    "Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
    $message . "\n\n";
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
    "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
    " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
    $data . "\n\n" .
    "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

    echo @mail($address, $email_subject, $message, $headers);
    echo $address;


}
```

Comment: Does the new server have a properly configured SMTP server (sendmail, postfix, qmail, etc.)? If so, check your maillog in /var/log/mail* ... Also, if you lose the @ before the email you might also get a useful error message to work with ...

Comment: Which mail server did you setup on your VPS?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably sitting in a queue somewhere on your server.  Check your php.ini.

Just to narrow it down a bit, try a really simple mail command...

`mail("youraddress@whatever.com", "Subject", "Testing 3, 2, 1...");`

Also in your script, if there were a problem, you wouldn't see it.  The `@` in front disables displaying of errors.  Since it is returning true though, I bet it's working just fine.  The `mail()` function doesn't verify that the e-mail was successfully sent... only that it was handed off to something else.  Your sendmail on the box may not be functioning.  Or for Windows, your SMTP server may not be set correctly.

There is also always the case of the e-mail sitting in a spam filter somewhere.

Comment: Ok, so I tried just executing that simple mail script, and it still isn't sending anything... any idea what I should be looking for in my php.ini file... I'm a little rusty. Sorry, I guess this is more of a server question than code...

Comment: Take a look at `sendmail_path` and `sendmail_from`.  If on Windows, check the STMP area.

Answer (score 0):

the problem could be that $usernum is not set, use global $usernum or pass it to the function also $scanreduser is never used

Comment: Oh, sorry 'bout that... usernum IS actually set, I was fiddling around when I copied the code to my clipboard and forgot to change it

Answer (score 0):

Good option is to use PHPMailer class (http://phpmailer.worxware.com/). I'm using this class and it works perfectly.